# Is it "arrive in the countryside" or "arrive at the countryside"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you explain what is the correct usage of this phrase?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you have attempted some research on your own. For example, we already have many questions, tagged [tag:at-in], which cover the differences in usage. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] on how to write good, answerable questions in our format. Our sister site for [English Languag Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

The preposition "at" is more commonly used to talk about a specific and geographically small location.

- I arrived at work.
- I arrived at the airport.

The preposition "in" is more commonly used to talk about geographically large areas.

- I arrived in America.
- I arrived in Knox County.
- I arrived in Yellowstone.

Following the above examples, I would suggest that countryside should get the "in" preposition.

- I arrived in the countryside.

Comment: Agree with @alwayssummer - an example of this is given in the Cambridge Dictionary under the Grammar section, where they suggest that you use 'at' if you imagine the place as a point, and 'in' if it is an area: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arrive

Answer (score 0):

I think in proper context both are correct.

You will see plains when you arrive in the countryside.

You will see a stranded barn when you arrive at the countryside.

(I hope I'm right)